# How to use malloc_stats in C program on Linux

Tags: linux, memory, c, gdb

I was trying to print the memory allocation statistics by calling malloc_stats() in my C program which is running on Linux. However it does not provide any outputs. According to the manpage of malloc_stats() the information is sent to the standard error. So how can I redirect the malloc_stats() info to a log file for my program?

I also tried calling malloc_stats() in gdb however that does not give me the proper info either:

```
(gdb) call malloc_stats()
[Switching to Thread 182928084768 (LWP 11950)]
$2 = -1759135936
(gdb)
```

What is wrong with my gdb?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change where the `malloc_stats` output goes, you'll need to redirect `stderr` yourself (e.g. use `freopen`) if you want that somewhere else.

If you have a recent-enough glibc (>= 2.10), you can use [`malloc_info(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_info.3.html) which takes a `FILE*` as one of its parameters (and outputs XML). Combine that with [`open_memstream(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) and you could get that in a memory buffer.

(I don't know what's wrong with your `gdb`, mine prints the stats just fine - GDB 7.3.1, glibc 7.15.)